# Python process in docker crashes when runned non-interactively

Tags: python, docker, shell, tmux, tty

I face an odd problem with an tool I found on github, it's a script that distributes an mjpeg stream: https://github.com/OliverF/mjpeg-relay

I create a docker image with the provided command (after initializing the submodule `git submodule update --init`):

```
docker build -t relay .
```

When I now run the container as follows (with the `-it` flag) the script runs fine, when removing the flag the container exits after some seconds.

```
docker run -it -p 54017:54321 relay "http://192.0.2.1:1234/?action=stream"
```

As I want to be able to start the script for multiple streams in a docker compose file, adding `restart: unless-stopped` leads to an endless loop of containers being restarted.

```
services:
   mjpeg:
       image: relay
       command: "http://192.0.2.1:1234/?action=stream"
       ports:
       - "54017:54017"
       restart: unless-stopped
```

I thought about encapsulating the command into `tmux` sessions, however I had no success with it. Or can you help me finding what leads to the crash of the script when running it non-interactive?

Thanks you very much!

Comment: Can you run `docker logs` to see if there's an error message when it crashes. Please add error messages and traceback to your question.

Comment: Looks like a related issue. 
https://github.com/OliverF/mjpeg-relay/issues/17